# Tomcat not able to find requested resource though it exists

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, tomcat, spring-mvc

My directory structure is

[image]

I am using Spring MVC with Apache Ivy. My web.xml is

```
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4" 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

  <display-name>Spring Web MVC Application</display-name>


  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

and my dispacher servlet spring configuration is

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">

    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WebContent/pages/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>

    </bean>

    <bean id="urlMapping"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
        <property name="mappings">
            <props>
                <prop key="/welcome.htm">testController</prop>
                <prop key="/login.htm">loginController</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="testController" class="TestController">
    </bean>

    <bean id="loginController" class="LoginController">
    </bean>

</beans>
```

I am testing localhost:8080/TestWebProject/login.htm. It is correctly hitting the Login controller. Yet I am getting following error

[image]

As you can see that path matches my directory structure. Not sure what am I missing. Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you try `/TestWebProject/pages/Login.jsp`?

Comment: Further to the above, this solution is suggested because WebContent is simply an Eclipse folder containing those resources to be deployed as your webapp. If you look in Tomcat's deployment directory for your webapp, the pages folder will be at the top level i.e. /TestWebProject/pages and not /TestWebProject/WebContent/pages

Comment: Yeah that solved this issue. Tx!

Answer (score 0):

Changed the path to `/TestWebProject/pages/Login.jsp` yet it showed me

```
java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation:
when resolving interface method "javax.servlet.jsp.JspApplicationContext.getExpressionFactory()Ljavax/el/ExpressionFactory;" the class loader (instance of org/apache/jasper/servlet/JasperLoader) of the current class, and the class loader (instance of org/apache/catalina/loader/StandardClassLoader) for resolved class, javax/servlet/jsp/JspApplicationContext, have different Class objects for the type javax/el/ExpressionFactory used in the signature
```

This occurs mainly because of dependencies that ivy downloads conflicts with those that Tomcat runtime provide.

Firstly go to `Project - > Properties - >target Runtime` and select `Apache Tomcat`

[image]

This solved the issue partially as Ivy download the transitive dependencies and it conflicts at runtime.

So I had to give options to disable transitive dependencies resolution. My Ivy finally had dependency

```
<dependency org="org.springframework" name="spring-context" rev="4.0.4.RELEASE" transitive="false"/>
<dependency org="org.springframework" name="spring-beans" rev="4.0.4.RELEASE" transitive="false"/>
<dependency org="org.springframework" name="spring-core" rev="4.0.4.RELEASE" transitive="false"/>
<dependency org="org.springframework" name="spring-web" rev="4.0.4.RELEASE" transitive="false"/>
<dependency org="org.springframework" name="spring-expression" rev="4.0.4.RELEASE" transitive="false"/>
```

This fixes it and yes as the comments suggest `/TestWebProject/pages/Login.jsp` worked and not `/TestWebProject/WebContent/pages/Login.jsp`.